# how to set skin for primefaces 1.1

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, skin

could you please explain how to set the skin for primefaces 1.1 ..

Answer (score 1):

you can try to add

```
<h:head>
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
            href="#{request.contextPath}/themes/redmond/skin.css" />
</h:head>
```

to your page and

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.skin</param-name>
    <param-value>none</param-value>
</context-param>
```

to web.xml

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.primefaces.org/themes.html:

> Installing Themes
>
> Applying a theme from Theme Gallery to
>   your PrimeFaces project is very easy,
>   you just need to download the theme
>   jar, add it your classpath and
>   configure PrimeFaces to use it.
>
> 1) You can either download the theme
>   manually from this page or using maven
>   via;
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
>   <artifactId>aristo</artifactId>
>   <version>1.0.0</version>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> 2) Next step is setting
>   primefaces.THEME parameter with the
>   theme name, you can also use an EL
>   expression for dynamic themes. view
>   plaincopy to clipboardprint?
>
> ```
> <context-param>
>               <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
>               <param-value>aristo</param-value>
>           </context-param>
> ```
>
> That's it!

I'm currently facing a problem like this, bhut have no real solution for that yet...

Comment: I think this will only work for Primefaces 2.2. In version 2.1 the themes weren't packed in a jar. But version 1.1 seems to have still another theme integration mechanism.

Comment: I just added the CSS to my portal enviroment and it worked ;)